# My code doesn't work when I use long long int and it works perfectly fine with int

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    int main(){
    int m,a[m],i,current; // on using long long int here
    cin>>m;
    a[0]=0; 
    a[1]=1; 
    current=1;
    for(i=2;i<=m;i++){
        a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i-2];
        a[i]=a[i]%10;   //taking last digit of the fibonacci sequence
        current=current+a[i]; //summing
        current=current%10;
        cout<<"current="<<current<<"\n";
       }
       cout<<"Last Digit of the sum upto "<<m<<"th Fibonacci number is "<<current;


}
```

My code doesn't work when I use long long int and it works perfectly fine with int.

Comment: What do you expect `int m, a[m]` to do?

Comment: You should include the error you are getting and the behavior you want to achieve....

Comment: First of all try to give more info as @GerasimosRagavanis says, furthermore, try to debug it if possible to reduce the question scope, thanks

Comment: please expand on the meaning of "doesn't work"

Answer (score 3):

`int m,a[m]`

This is:

a) undefined behaviour (use of m before it's initialised)

b) relying on a nonstandard gcc extension (variable-length c-style arrays)

You're 'lucky' it works with `int`

Comment: Most probably it doesn't work with `long long` is because its garbage value is greatly greater than the garbage of `int`. Then again it's by chance as you said.

Comment: I corrected the code and initialised m first. When using with input value <10^3,  works fine but gives Runtime Error on big input value. what can be done?

Comment: @MANUJAGARWAL you could try debugging the program?